# update on select ORA-01732

Tags: oracle, select, plsql

I get on oracle-server ORA-01732.
There are any other issues with this ORA, but it does not help me on my situation.

I select typicaly some data from two tables and i group these something like this:

```
SELECT  SUM (LG_ALL.HOURS) AS hour_sum,
            TO_CHAR (LG_ALL.WORK_DATE, 'YYYY.MM') AS singel_month,
            LG_ALL.EXPORTED
       FROM USER usr, 
            USER_ALLWC LG_ALL, 
      WHERE usr.user_id = LG_ALL.user_id            
            AND LG_ALL.EXPORTED = 'N'   
     GROUP BY 
            TO_CHAR (LG_ALL.WORK_DATE, 'YYYY.MM'),
            LG_ALL.EXPORTED
   ORDER BY usr.LOGNAME DESC
```

At next step, I have to set on table `USER_ALLWC`:

> LG_ALL.EXPORTED = 'Y'

Because of this, i wrap this into update-statement like 
[updates-based-on-queries => Inline View Method](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/updates-based-on-queries):

```
UPDATE (   SELECT  SUM (LG_ALL.HOURS) AS hour_sum,
                TO_CHAR (LG_ALL.WORK_DATE, 'YYYY.MM') AS singel_month,
                LG_ALL.EXPORTED
           FROM USER usr, 
                USER_ALLWC LG_ALL, 
          WHERE usr.user_id = LG_ALL.user_id            
                AND LG_ALL.EXPORTED = 'N'   
         GROUP BY 
                TO_CHAR (LG_ALL.WORK_DATE, 'YYYY.MM'),
                LG_ALL.EXPORTED
       ORDER BY usr.LOGNAME DESC ) allg
SET allg.EXPORTED = 'Y';
```

Sadly I get ORA-01732.
Can anyone explain, when I can update on select-statement and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

From [Oracle SQL Language Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_8004.htm#sthref6060):

> The view must not contain any of the following constructs:
>
> - A set operator
> - A DISTINCT operator
> - **An aggregate or analytic function**
>
> ...

Try simplifying it - the `sum`, `group by` etc. add no value anyway:

```
UPDATE (   SELECT  LG_ALL.EXPORTED
           FROM USER usr, 
                USER_ALLWC LG_ALL, 
          WHERE usr.user_id = LG_ALL.user_id            
                AND LG_ALL.EXPORTED = 'N'   
       ) allg
SET allg.EXPORTED = 'Y';
```

As long as there is a foreign key from `USER_ALLWC` to `USER` this should work.

In fact, assuming there **is** such a foreign key the whole statement is equivalent to:

```
UPDATE USER_ALLWC
   SET EXPORTED = 'Y'
 WHERE EXPORTED = 'N';
```

Comment: thx, i thought about this too. It seems, that i can not update on "group-by"-queries

Comment: That's right, [you can't](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_8004.htm#sthref6060)