# Oracle Apex Interactive Grid ORA-01732

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm having an issue while trying to update a table (on the front end) by using an Interactive Grid:

ORA-01732

Which is weird:

- I'm not using a view
- My query is based out of a single table only

My code:

```
select distinct 

SECTION,
ITEM_ID,
PRODUCT_NAME,
QUANTITY,
DISCOUNT,  -- This is the column to be updated by the user
MY_PRIMARY_KEY

FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE USER = lower(v('APP_USER'))
AND MY_ID = :P31_MY_ID
AND DEAL  = :P31_MY_ITEM_DEAL
```

Does anyone know what might be happening here?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [update on select ORA-01732](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46153168/update-on-select-ora-01732)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IG needs to be able to define each record with a unique identifier in order to successfully do execute the update statement. The keyword `DISTINCT` does not guarantee that. Try removing the `DISTINCT` from your query

Comment: thank you! Something so simple but effective, thanks!